# How to map System Enum's in Protobuf.Net

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

I have a class which has a property of type System.IO.FileAttribute (enum)

Upon serializing with protobuf-net I get the error:

```
No wire-value is mapped to the enum System.IO.FileAttributes.Hidden, System, Archive
```

How would I go about mapping system enum's to a Contract with Members?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a `[Flags]` enum, which doesn't really have a direct map in protobuf (as defined by google). I would simply re-expose as `int`:

```
public FileAttributes Attributes {get;set;}

[ProtoMember(12)] // whavever
private int AttributesSerialized {
    get { return (int)Attributes; }
    set { Attributes = (FileAttributes)value; }
}
```

Additionally, IIRC, I have already coded v2 to operate this way on `[Flags]` automatically, and to optionally allow pass-thru of enums  (to treat as the underlying value automatically).

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look at v2 or revert to the approach you describe.